# Needing assistance with Git, GitHub, and a DigitalOcean VPS for a version control solution

Tags: git, github, version-control

Please let me know if the question needs to be reworded, and my apologies in advance for any confusion.

I am attempting to create a version control solution using Git, GitHub and my VPS on DigitalOcean. As it currently stands, I have always had a DEV directory and a PRODUCTION directory, both on my DO VPS.

In the past, when finishing changes on the DEV directory, I would copy changed files manually over to my PRODUCTION directory. (Each of these directories is served to a different URL via Apache).

My goal is to have a Git repo in my DEV directory (where I make changes) sync up to my GitHub repo (https://github.com/jmwii1981/hello_world), which I have working. Then (this is the part I can't figure out). I'd like to pull changes from GitHub to my working directory, and by 'pull' I mean that I'd like to use GitHub's built in services to sync my changes from GitHub to the PRODUCTION directory on my server, however, I cannot seem to figure this out to save my life as every bit of documentation I've found so far has it's own flavor or method which is not inline with what I'm trying to achieve in my workflow.

My specific workflow would work out as follows:
(1) Make changes to code on DEV directory.
(2) 'git add .', 'git commit -m "my message"', 'git push origin'
(3) Git adds my changes, I commit those changes with my update message, I push those commits to my origin's master branch on GitHub using my SSH key.
(4) GitHub receives my changes and syncs them to my PRODUCTION directory.

Is this possible? I would assume it is, but I don't have enough experience with Git to make this happen. Thanks in advance for your help, excuse my naivety on this matter. I appreciate any detailed steps as I'm new to Git tech. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub cannot simply reach into your server and update the files, but what it can do is send messages when certain events happen. What you want to do is add a commit hook which sends your server a message. When your server receives the message, it should take all steps necessary to redeploy your application. (This may include stopping Apache, running `git pull`, and restarting Apache).

Git's [commit hook feature](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) allows you to run an arbitrary command or shell script on the server during a commit. Naturally GitHub doesn't give you all of that power; instead they have a set list of hooks which you can enable. The most general of these are called [webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-webhooks/). When you set up webhooks GitHub will do an HTTP POST to a url of your choosing.